# Flex TabBar drag drop

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, tabbar

I'm trying to implement drag and drop tabs in TabBar control, but I can't figure out the index of a tab to drop. I tried to use getObjectsUnderPoint() method but it didn't help me.
I need some implementation how to find a tab to drop.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use flexlib's SuperTabBar? It implements drag-n-drop perfectly.

http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/SuperTabNavigator_Sample.swf

Comment: It's not an option in my case.